# why JavaScript code i wrote is not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, checkbox

Its my code in html :

subscribe

```
<label for="visaBtn">Visa</label>
<input type="radio" name ="card" id="visaBtn">
<label for="mastercardBtn">MasterCard</label>
<input type="radio" name="card" id="mastercardBtn">
<label for="paypalBtn">Paypal</label>
<input type="radio" name="card" id="paypalBtn"><br>
<button id="myCheckBox">submit</button>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

body>

```
Then I wrote this function on JavaScript but when I am trying it on the browser it isn't working.
```

document.getElementById("myButton").onclick=function(){

```
const myCheckBox =document.getElementById("myCheckBox");
const visaBtn = document.getElementById("visaBtn");
const mastercardBtn = document.getElementById("mastercardBtn");
const paypalBtn = document.getElementById("paypalBtn");

if(myCheckBox.checked){
    console.log("You are subscribed");
}
else{
    console.log("You are NOT subscribed!");
}
 if(visaBtn.checked){
    console.log("You are paying with a Visa!");
 }
 else if(mastercardBtn.checked){
    console.log("You are paying with a Mastercard!");
 }
 else if(paypalBtn.checked){
    console.log("You are paying with a Paypal!");
 }
 else{
    console.log("You must select a payment type!");
 }
```

I want to know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Hi Saadat, are you getting any errors on the console??

Answer (score 0):

the id of the button is wrong
should be "myButton"

````
```<button id="myButton">submit</button> ```
````

```
     document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () { 
            const myCheckBox = document.getElementById("myCheckBox");
            const visaBtn = document.getElementById("visaBtn");
            const mastercardBtn = document.getElementById("mastercardBtn");
            const paypalBtn = document.getElementById("paypalBtn");
        
            if (myCheckBox.checked) {
                console.log("You are subscribed");
            } else {
                console.log("You are NOT subscribed!");
            }
            if (visaBtn.checked) {
                console.log("You are paying with a Visa!");
            } else if (mastercardBtn.checked) {
                console.log("You are paying with a Mastercard!");
            } else if (paypalBtn.checked) {
                console.log("You are paying with a Paypal!");
            } else {
                console.log("You must select a payment type!");
            }
        };
```

Comment: It is not allowed to ask for answers to be marked as answers or asking for upvotes. Beyond that, the question is Typo cause and as such should be answered but closed as `Not reproducible or caused by typos`. Such hints can be given as a comment but not as an answer.

Comment: While I assume you upvoted the question purely to allow the OP to upvote and check your answer it would be reputation rule infractions which are punishable.